# The meaning of 'Pool' in Computer Science

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems

While reading about `SIMD` on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), I noticed the use of the technical term `Pool` in the figure below:

[image]

I didn't know what it means; so after searching for it, I found only [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science)). Yet the definition wasn't very clear to me:

> In computer science, a pool is a set of resources that are kept ready
>   to use, rather than acquired on use and released afterwards. In this
>   context, resources can refer to system resources such as file handles,
>   which are external to a process, or internal resources such as objects

This is not the first time since I have seen the term - I found it on other CS-related materials in the past as well.

Does anyone have any idea about the meaning of 'Pool' in CS? or can provide any reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ***pool*** is basically some grouping.  It's kinda vague.

In that figure, the **"*data pool*"** is just some set of data while the **"*instruction pool*"** is just some set of instructions.  The figure means to show that a single instruction and multiple data go into the vector unit at a time, and then that single instruction is applied to each of the multiple data independently.

---

#### On the "*pooling*" design strategy

I clicked the link to ["Pool (computer science)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(computer_science)), Wikipedia.  That article's worded a bit confusingly because it's talking about a design strategy called "*pooling*" rather than discussing the term "*pool*" itself.

*Pooling* is when a resource is collected up into a pool for some reason.  Because it's such a vague term, it can apply in a lot of different situations, so it's hard to give a more specific description without overstating it.

But to give a common example, there's [***thread pooling***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) in which a bunch of threads are kept alive-and-waiting to do jobs.  This pattern's often useful when you might have a bunch of little jobs that you want to run on different CPU cores.  Then, whenever you want to run a job, you pick an available thread from the thread pool and have it run the job.

In principle, you don't actually need a thread pool; you could instead create a new thread each time you want to run a new job.  The problem's that threads can be expensive to create and dismiss, so if you're running a bunch of little jobs, it's often highly inefficient to keep creating/releasing threads.

That said, "*pooling*" is unrelated to what the SIMD diagram was referring to as a "*data pool*" and "*instruction pool*".  In that diagram, they just meant that they had a bunch of things data and instructions to use on them, which they vaguely referred to as existing in pools.

Comment: Just to confuse things further, it's unusual to separately "pool" instructions and data as the inputs to a modern functional unit. Rather, instructions are stored with the parameters which are already known, ready to issue as soon as a functional unit and/or final parameter becomes available. See, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_station